# Closed subalgebra generated by $T$ and $T^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $\mathcal{B}(\ell^p)$ denote the space of bounded linear operator on $\ell^p$ and let $T, T^{-1} \in \mathcal{B}(\ell^p)$ with $\|T\|=1$. I'm trying to understand what is the **closed subalgebra generated by $\{T,T^{-1}\}$** (let's call it $A$).

Surely $A$ contains operators of the form $\sum\limits_{k=-n}^{n}a_k T^k$. Since $A$ is closed, it must contains some operators of the form $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k T^k$. What conditions should $\{a_k\}_{k= -\infty}^\infty$ satisfy so that $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k T^k$

1) converges ?

2) belongs to $\mathcal{B}(\ell^p)$ ?

---

My educated guess : for both 1) and 2) it suffices that $\{a_k\}_{k=-\infty}^\infty$ belong to $\ell_1$ (but is it a necessary condition ?).

Let $\xi \in \ell_p$ with $\|\xi\|=1$, 
$$\left\|\left(\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k T^k\right)(\xi)\right\|_p \leq \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty |a_k|\cdot \|T(\xi)\|^k \leq \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty |a_k|.$$

Comment: What is the difference between "belongs to $\mathcal{B}(\ell^p)$" and "makes sense"?

Comment: Maybe 1) and 2) are the same, but I'm not taking any chance and split the question just in case there would be some $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k T^k$ that would be unbounded linear operator.

Comment: I see. Probably it would be better to say *converges* then.

Comment: The meaning of the phrase "the series converges" is fixed: how can it possibly converge to an element outside of the space that contains it terms? (There are ways to make sense of that but…)

Answer (score 1):

This is far from a complete answer (I don't think that a full characterization is at all possible, though I might be wrong).

The two questions are the same. The convergence of the series is the convergence (in $\mathcal B(\ell^p)$) of the sequence of partial sums. As $\mathcal B(\ell^p)$ is complete, if the series converges, it has to converge to a bounded operator. The story could be different if we consider convergence of the series in a topology in which $\mathcal B(\ell^p)$ is not complete.

The condition $a\in\ell^1$ is not necessary in general. For example, if $T=-I$ and $a_n=1/n$, the series converges even though the coefficients are not in $\ell^1$.

Even when $p=2$ the situation is not clear to me. If $T$ is selfadjoint, then the algebra you want is $C(\sigma(T))$, because it is a C$^*$-algebra. But when $T$ is not selfadjoint, it is not obvious what you get.

Comment: Please excuse my naive question but why is the subalgebra generated by $T$ a selfadjoint operator $C(\sigma(T))$ ?

Comment: When $\overline{\text{Alg}\,(T)}$ is an abelian C$^*$-algebra, the Gelfand transform is bijective.